# Firebase Security Rules Blocking Request when running a query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having a bit of trouble creating security rules for documents that are requested via a query. When I retrieve a full collection I have no issues with my security rules.

**Example - Only allow access for logged in users:**

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tags/{id} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Getting data:**

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs<Tag>(tagsCollection());
return querySnapshot.docs.map(t => t.data());
```

As a side note `tagsCollection()` refers to the following:

```js
export const tagsCollection = () => {
  const appFirestore = getAppFirestore();
  return collection(appFirestore, 'tags').withConverter(converter<Tag>());
};
```

**Onto the use case I have that isn't working. I have the following data retrieval via a query:**

```js
const noTestDataCasesQuery = query(
  collectionGroup(getAppFirestore(), 'cases'),
  where('isTest', '!=', true)
).withConverter(converter<Case>());

querySnapshot = await getDocs<Case>(noTestDataCasesQuery);
```

I've gone through the documentation ([Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)) and I do understand that rules need to match up with the query that is being run. With this in mind I'm trying to set up the following rule:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cases/{id} {
      allow read: if resource.data.isTest != true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Testing the above in the firebase emulator is resulting in:**

> FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: No matching allow statements

It's my first time setting up rules so I'm not too sure what might be the issue. I was also looking at this [blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003) which was helpful for me to understand the concept. However, following the examples there I'm still not able to make it work.

Comment: Why do you use a Collection Group query? Base on your security rules, `cases` seems to be a root collection.

Comment: Have you tried to use a simple query rather than a collection group query? Does it work that way?

Comment: Thank you both, that was the issue. Not sure why a collection group was being used. Just for my information I'm assuming that a collection group query needs to be used when querying multiple collections?

Comment: "I'm assuming that a collection group query needs to be used when querying multiple collections? " Yes. It will query all the collections **with the same name**, therefore these collections are subcollections.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @Renaud Tarnec:

> "I'm assuming that a collection group query needs to be used when querying multiple collections? " Yes. It will query all the collections with the same name, therefore these collections are subcollections.

---

Reference:

- [Collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)
- [Securely query data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_collection_group_queries)